# Bash, environment equivalent

Tags: command-line, bash

Let's say I have the following export in my ~/.bashrc

```
export MODE=vanilla
export PATH=/opt/bin/:/usr/bin/
```

And two scripts in my home

```
cat ~/setup_foo.sh
export MODE=foo
export PI_NUMBER=4
export PATH=/opt/bin/tool_foo/:$PATH

cat ~/setup_boo.sh
export MODE=boo
export PI_NUMBER=3
export PATH=/opt/bin/tool_boo:$PATH
```

The functionality I want to have:

```
$ echo $MODE
vanilla
echo $PATH
/opt/bin/:/usr/bin/

$ <<activate_foo>>
echo $MODE
foo
echo $PATH
/opt/bin/tool_foo/:/opt/bin/:/usr/bin/

$ <<activate_boo>>
echo $MODE
boo
echo $PATH
/opt/bin/tool_boo:/opt/bin/:/usr/bin/        --- NOTE, NO FOO HERE PRESERVED!

$ <<back_to_normal>>
echo $MODE
vanialla
echo $PATH
/opt/bin/:/usr/bin/    --- NO FOO AND BOO HERE!
```

What sort of tools, packages, bash should I use intsead of **<< pseudo commands >>** ?

If I just call ~/.setup_foo.sh it will overwrite variable, but do not clean up PATH

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest thing is to start a new bash shell and source the setup file, then exit from the shell to get back to your previous environment. Ex.:

```
$ printenv grep '[bf]oo'

$ bash --rcfile setup_foo.sh
$ printenv | grep '[bf]oo'
MODE=foo
PATH=/opt/bin/tool_foo/:/home/steeldriver/bin:/home/steeldriver/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

$ exit
exit
$ printenv grep '[bf]oo'

$ bash --rcfile setup_boo.sh
$ printenv | grep '[bf]oo'
MODE=boo
PATH=/opt/bin/tool_boo:/home/steeldriver/bin:/home/steeldriver/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

$ exit
exit
$ printenv grep '[bf]oo'
```

Comment: you could also combine/concat files `--rcfile <(cat ~/.profile setup.sh)`

Answer (score 0):

By deleting old entries first, you can prevent them from appearing multiple times.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

NEW_PATH=/opt/bin
PATH=$NEW_PATH:${PATH//$NEW_PATH:/}
echo $PATH

# And to remove your entry completely.
PATH=${PATH//$NEW_PATH:/}
echo $PATH
```

Another example using extglob list to handle multiple paths at once.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

FOO_PATH=/opt/foo
BAR_PATH=/opt/bar

PATH=$FOO_PATH:$BAR_PATH:${PATH//@($FOO_PATH|$BAR_PATH):/}
```